# Cisco ASA Port Forward using a custom RDP Port

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa, port-forwarding

I am having trouble setting up RDP access from outside the network using a custom port.  I would like for port 5000 to be translated externally to 3389 internally.  I have set it up with the commands below but I can't get RDP to work externally using port 5000.

I am using an ASA 5505 version 9.2 with ASDM version 7.8(1)

```
object network Internal_RDP_Server-1
 host 192.168.50.99
 nat (inside,outside) static interface service tcp 3389 5000 


access-list inbound permit tcp any object Internal_RDP_Server-1 eq 5000

access-group inbound in interface outside
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think you need a nat statement the point the external ip and port to the internal ip and port. In older asa it was like  'static (inside,outside) tcp 69.x.x.x 5000 192.168.50.99 3389 netmask 255.255.255.255'

Comment: Thanks.  Would you know the exact syntax of the statement.  I am familiar with the pre-8.3 commands but not so much with the newer ones.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen two variations of this command. The one you have done and the following

```
object network obj_192.168.50.99
 host 192.168.50.99
nat (inside,outside) static <-External IP Address-> service tcp 3389 5000
```

The difference is we've replaced the word "interface" with the real world external IP address.

Answer (score 1):

```
 nat (inside,outside) static interface service tcp 3389 5000
```

This line is correct if you mean to map requests to the OUTSIDE interface's IP address on port 5000 to the `192.168.50.99` IP address on port 3389.

```
access-list inbound permit tcp any object Internal_RDP_Server-1 eq 5000
```

This line, however is incorrect.  8.3+ ASA ACL syntax expects you to use the *real* attributes in all cases. You are specifying `eq 5000`, which is in fact the *mapped* attribute.

It should look like this:

```
access-list inbound permit tcp any object Internal_RDP_Server-1 eq 3389
```